# writing a meta refresh method for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

I want a method in app/controllers/application.rb that can prepend/append text to whatever template gets rendered.  Of course I can't call render twice w/o getting a double render error, so is this possible?

I want to redirect after a delay using a meta refresh.  Here's what I've got:

**app/controllers/application_controller.rb:**

```
def redirect_after_delay (url, delay)
  @redirect_delay = delay
  @redirect_url = url
  render
end
```

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <%= yield :refresh_tag %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

So then if I want to add a redirect-after-delay, I add the following to 1) my controller and 2) the action's view:
**app/controllers/my_controller.rb**

```
def my_action
  redirect_after_delay 'http://www.google.com', 3 if some_condition
end
```

**app/views/my_controller/my_action.html.erb**

```
<% content_for :refresh_tag do %>
  <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='<%=@redirect_delay%>;url=<%=@redirect_url%>'>
<% end %>
<h1>Please wait while you are redirected...</h1>
```

Since the `content_for` block never changes, is it possible to do this in some generic way so that I don't have to put `<%= yield :refresh_tag %>` in each template? (e.g. could `redirect_after_delay` add it into whatever template is going to be rendered?)

Comment: yeah i reformatted it so the question is at the top now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is to use an [after_filter](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html#M000529) in application_controller.rb to add the meta refresh tag if appropriate e.g.

```
def after_filter
  if @redirect_url and @refresh_delay
    # update controller.response.body to add meta refresh tag
  end
end
```

I'm not sure that this would be as efficient as using `yield :refresh_tag` as you would have to parse the HTML to insert the `meta` tag after the `head` tag but it is a possible approach to investigate.

Another idea would be to just put your header HTML in a partial that you then include in your other pages. e.g.

**Header partial:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <%= yield :refresh_tag %>
  </head>
```

**Footer partial:**

```
</html>
```

Comment: yeah i think i may be trying to make it too complicated, i will probably put something in the layout.  thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to put anything in the HTML, and worry about templates.  The meta tag is equivalent an HTTP header, which is really easy to send with Rails, e.g. in your controller:

```
def my_action
  header['Refresh'] = "5"
  render :my_view
end
```

Or you can refactor that out into a method in ApplicationController

```
def redirect_after_relay(url, delay)
  header['Refresh'] = "#{delay}; url=#{url}"
end
```

Comment: at least in rails 4, it is `headers`

Answer (score 1):

@aaronstacy

I was looking for the same functionality, so I borrowed and refined your approach.  Simply:

in app/controllers/application_controller.rb:

```
    def redirect_with_delay(url, delay = 0)
      @redirect_url, @redirect_delay = url, delay
      render
    end
```

in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<html>
  <head>
    [snip...]
    <% if @redirect_url %>
    <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='<%= @redirect_delay -%>;url=<%= @redirect_url -%>'>
    <% end %>
    [snip...]
  </head>
  [etc...]
```

This makes redirect_with_delay() available from any controller and in any view.  Works like a champ -- thank you for the inspiration.